# Symmetric axes in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to draw a contour plot with gnuplot, where I want to point out some special features with special colors.

I define the contour plot by

```
set pm3d map
set palette defined (-1 "red", -0.1 "red", 0 "white", 0.1 "blue", 1 "blue")
```

This results in a color gradient which has a small area with a gradient from red to white to blue and the remaining part is red for negative numbers and blue for positive numbers.

My problem is now, that I would like to set gnuplot automatically to a symmetric scaling of the z-axis. But by specifying `splot [][][-200:200] 'data' u 1:2:3` and a dataset with values from e.g. -300 to 100 gnuplot does an automatic rescale to `[-200:100]` which results in a misalignment of my colorscale (the white area is now around -50).

Is there a way to force a `zrange` or get an automatically symmetric scaled axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem, but have you considered:

```
set cbrange [-200:200]
```

From the documentation:

> The `set cbrange` command sets the range of values which are colored using
>    the current `palette` by styles `with pm3d`, `with image` and `with palette`.
>    Values outside of the color range use color of the nearest extreme.

Answer (score 2):

To force a z range, try

```
set zr [-200:200]
```

before your plot command.  To automatically scale the axis you could probably cook something up using `stats`.  The main trick is to keep in mind that the color bar is in relative units.  Something like this (untested):

```
datafile = 'data.dat'

stats datafile u 3 nooutput

# assume you want some data positive and some negative
if (stats_max*stats_min > 0) {
 print 'WARNING: all data has same sign.  Color bars may be weird.'
}

z0 = -1*min(abs(0.1*stats_min),abs(0.1*stats_max))
z1 = 0.0
z2 = -1*z0

set palette defined (stats_min "red", z0 "red", z1 "white",
                     z2 "blue", stats_max "blue")
```

Comment: The command `set zr [-200:200]` does not work. You can try this with `set pm3d map` and then `splot [-10:10][-10:10][] 5+10*sin(x)`. This does always result in a zrange from -6 to 16. The other method looks really promising. I will try this later.